# Formatting pandas dataframe printing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I have the following pandas dataframe that was converted to string with to_string().
It was printed like this:

```
S   T    Q     U    X    A    D
02:36  06:00  06:00  06:00  06:30  09:46  07:56
02:37  06:10  06:15  06:15  06:40  09:48  08:00
12:00  11:00  12:00  12:00  07:43  12:00  18:03
13:15  13:00  13:15  13:15  07:50  13:15  18:08
14:00  14:00  14:00  14:00      14:00  19:00
15:15  15:00  14:15  15:15      15:15  19:05
16:15  16:00  15:15  16:15      16:15  20:15
17:15  17:00  17:15  17:15      17:15  20:17
18:15      21:22  21:19  19:55  18:15  20:18
19:15      21:24  21:21  19:58  19:15  20:19
```

The gaps are due to empty values in the dataframe. I would like to keep the column alignment, perhaps by replacing the empty values with tabs. I would also like to center align the header line.
This wasn't printed in a terminal, but was sent over telegram with the requests post command. I think though, it is just a print formatting problem, independent of the telegram requests library.

The desired output would be like this:

```
  S      T      Q      U      X      A      D
02:36  06:00  06:00  06:00  06:30  09:46  07:56
02:37  06:10  06:15  06:15  06:40  09:48  08:00
12:00  11:00  12:00  12:00  07:43  12:00  18:03
13:15  13:00  13:15  13:15  07:50  13:15  18:08
14:00  14:00  14:00  14:00         14:00  19:00
15:15  15:00  14:15  15:15         15:15  19:05
16:15  16:00  15:15  16:15         16:15  20:15
17:15  17:00  17:15  17:15         17:15  20:17
18:15         21:22  21:19  19:55  18:15  20:18
19:15         21:24  21:21  19:58  19:15  20:19
```

Comment: This probably has to do with tab size. Change the tab size to 2 in notepad. Or replace tabs with 2 spaces and all should align. Or baybe 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dataframe style.set_properties to set some of these options like:

```
df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
```

read more here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but unfortunately, this  suggestion didn't work for me. When I print to a terminal, there's no problem with the alignment, except for the header line. I did not notice any difference by using df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}) or not. The headerline alignment I can fix with pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center'). I believe the alignment problem is with the requests library or the Telegram app where I print it.